How to use React Signals with arrays?
I'm trying to use Signals (@preact/signals-react) to reduce re-rendering with large data objects. In my case, I'm getting object from a network request, and tends to change frequently with live updates.
for direct properties, it works well, reducing the number of rerenders:
export function Root(){
  const mySignal = useSignal({ sub: { val: 1 }, arr: [{id: 1, name: "bob"}] });

  return <div>
    <Counter signal={mySignal} /> 
    <Array signal={mySignal} /> 
  </div>
}

function Counter({ signal }) {
  const counter = useComputed(() => signal.value.counter);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          signal.value = { ...signal.value, counter: signal.value.counter + 1 };
        }}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

In this case, only Counter rerenders when incrementing .
This is true also when we have useSignals().
However, with arrays the situation is different:
function ArrayConsumer({ mySignal }: { mySignal: MySignal }) {
  const arr = useComputed(() => mySignal.value.someArr);

  return (
    <>
      {arr.value.map((item) => (
        // renders and edits {item.name}
        <ArrayItem key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

Because I use arr.value directly, any time the array changes, the whole list gets rerendered.
I expected some sort of signalMap() method, but the docs only suggest using the signal.value there.
One solution is to wrap the individual list items in a Signal, but that seems like a bad practice? I really thought signals give similar performance and devexp to Mobx, but without lists support it's much less useful.
// ideal solution
function ArrayItem(item) {
  // assuming item is a signal too
  // although I'm missing a way to do that
  const name = useComputed(() => item.value.name);
  return (
    <div
      // pseudo code
      contentEditable
      onChange={(e) => (item.value = { ...item.value, name: e.target.value })}
    >
      {name}
    </div>
  );
}


ArrayConsumer is the one that passes item into ArrayItem. If it does not rerender, react can't pass the new prop when you update specific item. Or when you add/delete item, it needs to rerender in order to execute the map method again. I don't think there is something that can be done to change this, this is how react works. ArrayConsumer have to rerender, but if you don't want to rerender all ArrayItems, you can try using React.memo

@OktayYuzcan I don't think you know how signals work, as your comment is quite incorrect. Signals are mutable state containers, you do not need rerenders in many cases.

I understand that not anything should rerender. But ArrayConsumer is the one that renders the list. If it does not rerender you can't add / delete. You have not provided an example how you update your array.

@OktayYuzcan You're confusing me with OP, and you absolutely can add & delete without rerendering. That's core functionality that signals provides. It bypasses rerenders.

You definitely can't. ArrayConsumer returns a fragment that has array of N items. This is what react-dom receives. If you want to add new item, react-dom has to rerender it again in order to receive fragment + M amount of items. The example below is the same. For is a component that rerenders every time the array changes. In the implementation it uses Map where it only appends, never removes, this will lead to memory leaks. The item is passes as key, I don't see how this gonna work, if the item is an object, it can't be used as key, if it is number there will be dublicate keys

@OktayYuzcan Again, please read what the integration does, it bypasses react-dom nearly entirely. That's the whole point, we aren't rerendering components. You're entirely mistaken. Please read up on what the library does before coming to sites like this to spout incorrect information.

@rschristian If the signal value is number or string, yes, it might do it. But this is an array of react elements. What exactly is the incorrect information here? That the implementation of the For does lead to memory leaks or it uses the items itself as a key? Look what that For is. It is a component. And it rerenders every time that array changes. It is true that ArrayConsumer won't rerender but the For will. It just caches its children based on the item's reference. It does not mean that For will never rerender.

No, <For> doesn't rerender in the given implementation. Signals pass through components without rerendering them, that is a fundamental principle. The array passed to it can update and change, resulting in an updated list of <Items>, without issue. Please just read the docs, they answer this and more. This thread is far from productive if you haven't. What you've said is entirely incorrect in the given scope. There should not be a memory leak in the given example as the components will only be ran once.

@rschristian I tested it myself and the For was rerendering. What would be the point to store them in a Map if it renders only once? What am I missing? Can you provide a reproducable code so we can see that the For is actually not rerendering? https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-r6brvr?file=src%2FCounter.jsx This is my experiment. When you add, if you open the console it gives warning for keys. When you click refresh, it stores the new items to the Map without clearing the old ones

The library is meant to be a core set of primitives, and therefore doesn't address utilities that can be added from userland. Such things are quite easy to build out yourself. Here's a helpful utility that Jason/developit wrote a while back:
const Item = ({ v, k, f }) => f(v, k);

/**
 * Like signal.value.map(fn), but doesn't re-render.
 */
export function For({ each, children: f, fallback }) {
    let c = useMemo(() => new Map(), []);
    return (
        each.value?.map(
            (v, k, x) => c.get(v) || (c.set(v, (x = <Item {...{ key: v, v, k, f }} />)), x)
        ) ?? fallback
    );
}

Now for your example, you can use it like so:
function ArrayConsumer({ mySignal }: { mySignal: MySignal }) {
  const arr = useComputed(() => mySignal.value.someArr);

  return (
    <>
      <For
        each={arr}
        children={(item) => (
          <ArrayItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
}


interesting, though not exactly? apart from the memory leak, it doesn't pass a signal to the ArrayItem

Not sure I follow, you want to pass a signal to <ArrayItem>? If so, you need to use nested signals, which your example doesn't show. Once you unwrap with .value, the result is no longer a signal. You'll need to provide more information.

yes that's what I wrote. I wonder if it makes sense to have nested signals, and if it is best practice. Technically I see it's very possible, practically it could be a pain

Yes, it's absolutely fine to use nested signals if that's what your case depends upon. FWIW, I am a maintainer of Preact Signals (though I usually stick to the Preact end of things).

ah I was hoping for some magic trick. I will write an answer showcasing nested signals. It does make model more complicated though, but I guess we can make something like ArrayItemObj.create = () => signal(new ArrayItemObj())

isn't it weird though that useComputed() has no problem with nested values (like obj.a.b.c) but has a problem with arrays? I guess arrays are "infinite" whereas objects are finite, we'd have the same problem with Record<>

It's a set of primitives, deep reactivity can be (and has been) trivially added on top. There's a couple different "deepsignal" packages that offer this. Objects don't work either, so I'm not quite sure what you're referring to.

very interesting, is there a package you would recommend?

https://github.com/EthanStandel/deepsignal and https://github.com/luisherranz/deepsignal are both great, though the latter is a bit different syntactically.
